# Dart + IntelliJ / Debug on port 3030 like DartEditor

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, dart-editor

The DartEditor starts a little WebServer on port 3030 for debugging. I could not find a way the do the same with IntelliJ IDEA 12.5.x - any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a similar feature called built-in web server - see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/built-in+web+server for details. Not sure if it works in Idea 12.*, but for sure it's available in Idea 13 EAP